# Extract book cover page using isbndb android

Tags: android, lookup, isbn

I am using ISBN-DB for book lookup using ISBN number. I cam able to extract the name, title, etc using the same. But how to extract the cover page info using ISBNDB? If not feasibe, can anyone kindly guide on any other ISBN lookup api for android to accomplish the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISBN DB does not have any info for the book cover.  An alternative would be to use the Google books API which returns a JSON file that contains a tag with links to both a small and large thumbnail of the book cover.   Here is an example search with the API

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781605906768

You can see the tag imageLinks contains some URLS for images.

Hope that helps!